# automation testing framework/software for GUI related hardware applications

Tags: python, user-interface, testing, automation, sikuli

I'm trying to find a perfect automation testing framework/software for GUI related hardware applications like sikuli, but sikuli(image recognition) is not having stability, So please suggest me some other tools which is work as sikuli without image recognition.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you please better explain what you mean by "GUI related hardware applications"? And examples?

Comment: There are many things about test application that can change your framework choice. Which OSes does it support? What GUI dev. framework is used: QT, WinForms, WPF, Tk, MFC, wxWidgets? Please be concrete.

Comment: @Viktor, means all desktop related applications testing

Comment: @Vasily, all desktop related applications testing

Answer (score 0):

If you have a script that has it's code build up properly the script is also much more stable.

For example:

```
# Example 1
Image1 = ("Image1.png")
find(Image1)
click(Image1)

# Example 2
Image1 = ("Image1.png")
try:
    find(Image1)
    click(Image1)
except:
    pass
```

Example 2 will give you a more robust script, because if "Image1.png" is not present, it will not terminate the script.

Sikuli is good for image recognition, but it still needs good images. 
You could also try making use of the word recognition, and keybord controls to to shortvuts etc.

For example text reading, you can add:

```
Settings.OcrTextSearch = True
Settings.OcrTextRead = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your sikuli script with java program.

reference - http://doc.sikuli.org/faq/030-java-dev.html